# extract rows with specific value in a specific column using bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have 1000 text files and each file is tab delimited with following format

```
John    32     NY     12     USA
Peter   78.    CA.    8.     USA
Stef.   67.    CA.    12.    USA
```

I want to extract all those line where fourth column is exactly 12. This is what I've done:

```
file='random'

FILES=/home/user/data/*.txt
for f in $FILES; 
do 
echo $f
filename=$(basename $f)
awk -F"\t" '$4 == 12' $f >  /home/user/extra/$file/$filename; 
done
```

But this produces empty files and I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Insights will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't want to match the `12.` line, right? Use string comparision: `$4 == "12"`. Also run your script through https://shellcheck.net and implement its suggestions.

Comment: Oh, and `for f in /home/user/data/*.txt;`.

Comment: Yeah, the glob `*` does not expand in the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes to understand some of the issues in your script and copy/paste any shell script you write into https://www.shellcheck.net/ until you get the fundamentals down.

Regarding `But this produces empty files` - sure, for any give command `cmd` with

```
for f in *; do
    cmd "$f" > "out$f"
done
```

you're creating an output file for each input file in the shell loop so if any input file doesn't match `$4==12` in your awk script (the `cmd` in this case) you'll still get an output file, it'll just be empty. If you don't want that you could do:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
for f in *; do
    cmd "$f" > "$tmp" &&
    mv -- "$tmp" "out$f"
done
```

and write `cmd` to exit with a succ/fail status like `grep` does when it finds a match (trivial in awk), or you could check the size of `"$tmp"` before the `mv`:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
for f in *; do
    cmd "$f" > "$tmp" &&
    [[ -s "$tmp" ]] &&
    mv -- "$tmp" "out$f"
done
```

You don't need a shell loop or other commands for this, though, just 1 call to awk to process all of your files at once. Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box do **only** this

```
awk -v file='random' -F'\t' '
    FNR == 1 {
        close(out)
        f = FILENAME
        sub(".*/","",f)
        out = "/home/user/extra/" file "/" f
    }
    $4 == 12 {
        print > out
    }
' /home/user/data/*.txt
```

If you want a string instead of numeric comparison so that `12.` doesn't match `12` then do `$4 == "12"` instead of `$4 == 12`.

In the above `file` is a poor choice of variable name to hold the name of a **directory** but I left it alone to avoid changing anything I didn't have to.